# How to get a whole entity in Jhipster using mappers and DTOs?

Tags: jhipster, mapstruct

I'm new to mapstruct and I have a couple questions that I could not find an answer for.

I have an Entity1 (object) that has a Many2Many relationship with the Entity2. In this case, my Entity1DTO can bring all the data (Swagger) from Entity1 using a Set:

```
    private Set<Entity2DTO> appusers = new HashSet<>();
```

That Set has all the information about all the Entity2DTO objects.

Then, I have another Entity3 with a relation (One2Many) with Entity1. When I want to get all the same information with Entity3 (One2Many) it only brings the ID of Entity3 and the rest of the attributes are null.

```
    private Entity3DTO entity3;
```

Mapper:

```
@Mapping(target = "entity3", source = "entity3", qualifiedByName = "id")
Entity3DTO toDto(Entity3 s);
```

If I change the mapper and include, not only the id, but the other attributes (it will work), but I want to ask if there is an easier or more direct way to change the DTO or the mapper to bring the rest of the data, is there any?

And... Why it brings all data in the case of the Set, but not in the other case?

[MapStruct documentation is](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/) not clear enough, so if you have any other examples with Jhipster that would be great.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not really a JHipster question so I added mapstruct tag to give your question more exposure from mapstruct experts. If you don't like mapstruct examples, you can still write a Mapper that does not use it as I explained in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65338134/why-do-i-need-mapstruct-for-when-using-jhipster . It might sound more work but you are going to do it anyway in frontend. Not related to MapStruct but I suspect also that you have N+1 query performance issues with lazy loaded relationships, have you checked logs with show_sql set to true?

Comment: Thanks Gaël. I still do not know how to write the mapper that do not use mapstruct. Do you have any example? Mapstruct documentation is hard to understand. Thanks for the tag.

Comment: What is your level in Spring/Java? It's important to mention it in your questions in order to get the right level of details in answers. Writing a Mapper is just about calling setters with values from getters. You can find an example by searching for the `Entity1MapperImpl.java`  class generated by MapStruct in your `target` directory.

Comment: I see you are an expert and with all the respect, I disagree. You should always explain things as clear and detailed as possible, since not only the one who is missing something are going to read it. All types of people will read it and you can help them too, not only the experts. Asume that the level is really low and you will help the most. My experience is greater than my Spring knwoledge for sure. Jhipster's book and website do not explain this, that's why you find the questions here. The question still is how can I get all the entity info in the DTO (and see it in Swager)?
Thanks Gäel.

Comment: I'd agree with you if the people answering you is paid to do so, otherwise it's just asking for more time from someone that does it for free.  Mappers and DTOs can be plain java objects without requiring any library. You say your question is still the same but you don't provide feedback about my suggestions and you don't provide more info about the difficulties you have encountered in applying them, and then you add another question about swagger-ui, it's endless. I'm sorry but I give up, it's consuming too much time.

Comment: Thanks anyway Gaël. I think that you do the things the best way you can, whether you get paid for it or not, it is another issue. StackOverflow spirit is about helping, not about getting paid, right?. I didn't answer to your suggestions because I do not understand what to do. Sorry for my part, but yes, it has been a complete loss of time. Hope you can find other guys that can use your help! No hard feelings, really appreciate that you tried to help me.

Comment: I've read the question and I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you perhaps share a minimal example where the problem is happening so I can understand it better and be able to help?

Comment: Entity3 has a `OneToMany` with Entity1 or Entity2?

Comment: No, sorry. It has a One2Many with Entity1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I have understood correctly, but I'm guessing your problem is that you want `Entity1Mapper` to map all the attributes of the nested `Entity3` instead of just its `id`.

In your `Entity1Mapper.java`, change this:

```java
@Mapping(target = "entity3", source = "entity3", qualifiedByName = "id")
Entity1DTO toDto(Entity1 s);
```

Into this:

```java
@Mapping(target = "entity3", source = "entity3")
Entity1DTO toDto(Entity1 s);
```

This way you are telling MapStruct to use the full `toDto(...)` mapping method instead of `toDtoId(...)` that only fills the object ID.

### Example project

I've generated a small JHipster 7.0.1 project to reproduce and fix your issue.

This is the JDL:

```
entity Entity1
entity Entity2
entity Entity3 { name String }

relationship ManyToMany { Entity1 to Entity2 }
relationship OneToMany { Entity3 to Entity1 }

dto all with mapstruct
```

With the freshly generated project you can start it up and go to the *Entity1* main page and edit the first one to add an *Entity3*. If you inspect the `GET` call in the detail page for the *Entity1* you just edited you will see that *Entity3* only has an `ID` (notice how the name is `NULL`) as was expected.

```json
{
  "id" : 1,
  "entity2s" : [ {
    "id" : 1
  } ],
  "entity3" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : null
  }
}
```

Then go to `Entity1Mapper.java` and remove the `, qualifiedByName = "id"` part in the mapping of `entity3`. Like so:

Before:

```java
    @Mapping(target = "entity2s", source = "entity2s", qualifiedByName = "idSet")
    @Mapping(target = "entity3", source = "entity3", qualifiedByName = "id")
    Entity1DTO toDto(Entity1 s);
```

After:

```java
    @Mapping(target = "entity2s", source = "entity2s", qualifiedByName = "idSet")
    @Mapping(target = "entity3", source = "entity3")
    Entity1DTO toDto(Entity1 s);
```

Wait for the server side to recompile and reload the page, and there you have it:

```json
{
  "id" : 1,
  "entity2s" : [ {
    "id" : 1
  } ],
  "entity3" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Incredible Account"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vicpermir, you understood it correctly, but it does not work (and i'm not saying that it is wrong, it might be something else and i will give you the award if it is not a mapstruct issue). I commented out the JsonIgnoreProperties, but still does not work. If I can contact by chat (or email) I can send you the whole code and you might take a look.

Comment: Make sure you make the change I suggested in your `Entity1` mapper (not `Entity3` mapper) and recompile your serverside, it should work. Otherwise, add your version of JHipster to the question and I'll do a quick test to confirm.

Comment: I did, but it does not work. Jhipster: Version 7.0.1

Comment: I've added an example, reproduced your issue and fixed it just like I told you in the original answer. I don't know what else to tell you, sorry.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. Now, it does. Anyway, did you find the information on Mapstruct documentation? (where?). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, it's here: [Method selection based on qualifiers](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers).

Comment: Thanks vicpermir. I'm trying to find the documentation that explains the difference between qualifiedByName = "id" (which only brings the id) and qualifiedByName = "headlineSet" (which aparently, brings the whole Set of objects). Any idea? Thanks